# how can i send imagedata on server using httppost in android?

Tags: android, http-post

I tried to convert image data into "String str=Base64.encodeToString(imagedata, Base64.DEFAULT);" and then i tried to send it but its not working.

Even i tried below,

```
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setCharset(MIME.UTF8_CHARSET);

        builder.addBinaryBody("file",imagedata);

        httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
```

still i can't send an image.

Server url on which i am trying to send is as below,

"http://192.168.1.8:88/erp/demo.nsf/(demo)?operation&file=imagedata"

Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your url is supposed to carry parameters. Any parameters you use must be added in the builder as text. Here's some code I recently used to do the same thing.:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String textFileName = params[0];
        String message = "This is a multipart post";
        String result =" ";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/test/upload_file_test.php");
        File file = new File(textFileName);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        builder.addBinaryBody("uploaded_file", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, textFileName);
        builder.addTextBody("text", message, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);

        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            System.out.println("Response: " + s);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

I used the text part to send a message with the image.

Comment: I tried to use to the code that you provided. i am taking ""http://192.168.1.8:88/erp/demo.nsf/(demo)?operation" as an url. and then tried to implement like  MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        builder.addBinaryBody("file", imagedata, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "file"); \n but it gives me "Nosuchfield" error.

Comment: Copy your error log and put it up so we can see the source of the problem. Also provide any context.